# Lindenmayer systems in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractals

Good evening,

I am trying to understand how the TikZ library lindenmayersystems works, more precisely I have some problems with the following code, that I tried to make as clear as possible :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % I just store the initial length
  \newlength\initialstep
  \setlength\initialstep\pgflsystemstep

  % Computation of an angle
  \pgfmathparse{180-180/5} % will be less trivial at the end
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angle\pgfmathresult

  % Computation of a ratio
  \pgfmathparse{2*0.5/(1-0.5)} % this seems trivial but this is just a particular case
  \pgfmathsetmacro\scaling\pgfmathresult

  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{KochC}{
    % d does a turn around
    \symbol{d}{
    \pgflsystemleftangle=180
    \pgflsystemturnleft
    \pgflsystemleftangle=\angle
    }

    % move on a certain portion
    \symbol{c}{
    \pgflsystemstep=\scaling*\initialstep
    \pgflsystemdrawforward
    \pgflsystemstep=\initialstep
    }

    % new measures
    \symbol{n}{
    \pgflsystemstep=\scaling*\initialstep
    }

    \rule{A->A[cA]nd-A-A-A-A}
  }
  \draw[blue,line cap=round] [lindenmayer system={KochC,axiom=A,order=1}] lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error I have is `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`, which does not seem very relevant, unless I am completely mistaken.

The purpose of this code is to draw a line segment, with some centered portion of it replaced by a n-gone, here n is 5. Another problem I have is to make this n be any natural number, and can't seem to find a way but this is another question.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Pierre

PS: the reason why I store pgflsystemstep at the beggining is because this code will actully be used in some context where it makes sense. I kept this line, if maybe there is a problem with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! The errors come from the stars you have before `\initialstep`. You define `\initalstep` as length by saying `\newlength\initialstep`, so you do not want to use `*`s. The following, where I shortened the `\pgmathsetmacro` stuff a bit, works. I am using [your code from the comment below](https://pastebin.com/nxg7wcu7) (with minor modifications) because the result looks great.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}

%\newcommand{kochC}[1]
%{

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % je stocke pfgsystemstep dans une nouvelle variable initialstep : c'est la longueur du premier segment
    \newlength\initialstep

    % je calcule l'angle dont il faut tourner pour faire un polygône réglier à n côtés
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{360/5} % changer 5 en le nombre de côtés qu'on veut

    % je calcule le facteur de scaling
    \pgfmathsetmacro\scaling{2*0.33/(1-0.33)} %\pgfmathparse{2*#1/(1-#1)}

    \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{KochC}{
      % s initialise les données
      \symbol{s}{
       \def\pgflsystemleftangle{-\angle}
       \def\pgflsystemrightangle{180-\angle}
       \setlength\initialstep\pgflsystemstep
     }

      % avancer sur une portion de longueur c sans tracer
      \symbol{c}{
       \pgflsystemstep=\scaling\initialstep
       \pgflsystemmoveforward
       \pgflsystemstep=\initialstep
     }

      % nouvelles mesures
      \symbol{n}{
       \pgflsystemstep=\scaling\pgflsystemstep
     }

     \rule{F->sF[cF]n-F+F+F+F}
   }
   \draw[blue,line cap=round] [lindenmayer system={KochC,axiom=F,order=1}] lindenmayer system;
 \end{tikzpicture}
%}

%\kochC[0.5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

- If you deal with lengths, you cannot use `*` (unless you use something like `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` but this is not necessary here) and you cannot set lengths with `\def` but with `\setlength` or just `<new length>=<factor><other length>`, where `<factor>` is a number. (Notice that `=` is sometimes safer because I believe to remember that some package redefines `\setlength` but this is not important here.)
- If you redefine macros, you could use `\renewcommand` or here `\pgfmathsetmacro` or `\def`. However, the latter two do not warn you if the macro didn't exist beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It would be so nice if you could also give me a clue on why the result is a simple line segment instead of what I am expecting, i.e. a line segment with a pentagone around its center. Thanks again

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to start a chat so : here https://pastebin.com/5QAvjM3c is my current code. I figured out that several things were incorrect : I was redefining variables with "=" instead of \def for example. The current code doesn't compile but I feel like we're almost there

Comment: @elidiot Indeed. All you need to do is to replace `\def\pgflsystemstep{\scaling\initialstep}` by `\setlength\pgflsystemstep{\scaling\initialstep}`  or `\pgflsystemstep=\scaling\pgflsystemstep` (twice) and your code works. (I should have caught the `=` but I thought they were counters... ). So the upshot is that you can redefine lengths with either `=` or `\setlength` and macros with `\def` (sometimes dangerous), `\renewcommand` or in this context with `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for everything. Here is the final example https://pastebin.com/nxg7wcu7 which gives exactly what I wanted.